# Android: downloaded file size less than its actual size

Tags: android

I want to update my application automatically
This is the code i am using

```
public void Update(String apkurl){
      try {
            URL url = new URL(apkurl);
            HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            c.setRequestMethod("GET");
            c.setDoOutput(true);
            c.connect();

            String PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/";
            File file = new File(PATH);
            file.mkdirs();
            File outputFile = new File(file, "DeliverReceipt.apk");
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

            InputStream is = c.getInputStream();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int len1 = 0;
            while ((len1 = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                fos.write(buffer, 0, len1);
            }
            fos.close();
            is.close();//till here, it works fine - .apk is download to my sdcard in download file

            /*Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/apk/" + "DeliverReceipt.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
            startActivity(intent);  //installation is not working        
            */
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Update error!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
  }
```

The downloaded file is just 20kb size, which is less than the original
how can i solve this problem?
thank you
*noted : if i try this url in browser it's work, an apk can be downloaded

Comment: What is the original file size? Minor differences can show up because of the way file gets stored on the disk (e.g. block size, fragmentation).

Answer (score 0):

You should probably flush before you close the file, using `fos.flush()`

Comment: it's can't solved..i try add this code in my coding, but still not worked..in my web service, when i request with parameter it return file with autodownload